# Does anyone know how to remove the board and scroll bar from this iframe embed code

Tags: html, iframe, embed

Does anyone know how to remove a border and scroll bar from an iframe embed code from an embed.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the scroll bar, but the border is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two attributes `frameborder="0" scrolling="no"` to your iframe tag

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="Your URL"></iframe>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Please disregard the previous comment. All systems go. Gratitude to you!